# How to deal with GORM commit/rollback error

Tags: go, transactions, go-gorm

I just found that in GORM, the transaction commit might return error, like:

```
tx := db.begin()
// do somthing here
err := tx.Commit().Error
```

Also it appears when roll back

```
tx := db.begin()
// do somthing here
err := tx.Rollback().Error
```

I wonder how would this error happens?

And if happen, would GORM itself do any recover functions to deal with pending transactions?

Or is it necessary for me to do something if rollback or commit returns error?

BTW is there any best practice for such transaction issues in GORM?

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder how would this error happens?

In exactly the same situations where you might get an error from some other database call:

- Network connection failure
- Database, disk, or hardware failure
- Permissions problems
- Syntax errors in the command
- Data inconsistency errors

For `Begin`, your error options are somewhat limited, since there's no data (yet) that could be inconsistent. But for `Commit` and `Rollback` any of those errors are possible, as well as the case where there's no active transaction to be committed (because of a previous error, because it was already committed, or because it was already rolled back).

> And if happen, would GORM itself do any recover functions to deal with pending transactions?

No. There's no possible way GORM could, since it doesn't know your application logic. As with all failures, of all types, it is up to the programmer to determine what is the appropriate action. Maybe you should retry. Maybe you should only retry N times. Maybe you should ignore the failure and continue as if it succeeded. Maybe you should return an error to the user. Maybe you should panic and crash the entire program.  GORM obviously has no way of knowing the proper response.

> Or is it necessary for me to do something if rollback or commit returns error?

As eluded to in my last paragraph, only you can know this.  What is your application attempting to do? Waht is the right thing to do in case of a failure?

> BTW is there any best practice for such transaction issues in GORM?

This has nothing to do with GORM.  "Best practice" in handling errors is simply to reason about what an error indicates, and what your application ought to do in that case.

Comment: It seems I neglect the error handling before. Sad :/

Got to follow my business logic to rewrite commit & rollback part.

Thanks for your detailed reply!

Comment: @Lo1nt: It's a lesson every developer eventually learns the hard way. Better to learn it sooner than later, though :)

Comment: Yup! still long way to go for me :3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for

```golang
func (db *DB) Rollback() *DB {
    if committer, ok := db.Statement.ConnPool.(TxCommitter); ok && committer != nil {
        if !reflect.ValueOf(committer).IsNil() {
            db.AddError(committer.Rollback())
        }
    } else {
        db.AddError(ErrInvalidTransaction)
    }
    return db
}
```

So this only checks if `tx` instance is generated from `Begin()` method and isn't a normal `*gorm.DB` instance. So in Rollbacks case, error checking isn't crucial(but of course recommended)

For `.Commit()` of course you should check errors because a commit is doing all your database interactions during transactions. So if any one of them returns an error `.Commit()`'s error will give you access to that.

Here is an example of using it from documentation
https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#A-Specific-Example